# Parabola: x-coordinate is negative when it should be positive.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, conic-sections

I'm teaching myself math. I was working on $y = -x^2 + 8x$ and I used the quadratic equation to determine the x-coordinates. I ended up with $(0,0)$ and $(-8,0)$. The vertex is $(4,16)$ and the y-intercept is $(0,0)$. The thing is, x coordinate of root should be a positive number$=+8,$  otherwise I cannot have a parabola.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

You have that $-x^2 + 8x = -x(x-8)$ so the intersections of the parabola with the $x$-axis are $(0,0)$ and $(8,0)$ as you remarked. You probably made a sign mistake somewhere along your computations.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have the parabola $$y = (-x^2 + 8x -16) +16 \iff y= -(x^2-8x+16)+16 \iff (y-16)= -(x-4)^2$$

This parabola opens downward (we see the coefficient before the squared function of x is negative (-1).

A parabola given by $y-b = m(x-a)^2$ has vertex at $(a, b)$.  In this case, that makes the vertex $(4, 16)$.

The parabola intersects the x-axis when $y= 0$, which means, in this case, when $x^2-8x = x(x-8) = 0.$ This means that either $x=0$, or $x-8 = 0 \iff x = 8$. So the points $(0, 0)$ and $(8, 0)$ are the two points of the parabola at which the parabola intersects the x-axis.  It seems your work was fine, except for the sign error with respect to the point $(0, 8).$

[image]

Comment: Hope ok, else feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

$y = -x^2 + 8x ; \, 0= x( 8-x) ,  \rightarrow x= +8,0 $

It is a simple sign error you made. Maximum value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice from the equation $y=-x^2+8x$ is the leading negative sign. This means the parabola opens downward. You don't state that you know this fact. However, since the vertex you give is correct and lies above the $x$-axis, you should have realized this to be true.

So you decided the intercepts were at $(0, 0)$ and $(-8, 0)$. The $x-$coordinate of the vertex should lie between these two values (indeed, at the average). But you noted the vertex is at $(4, 16)$, not $(-4, 16)$.

As a former teacher, I can tell you that most students would accept these answers as true, and not check to see if they make sense. You have checked, and for that I congratulate you. To reward this good habit of yours, I have written this long(ish) post.

I think the mistake you made was in seeing the plus sign in the original equation, $y=-x^2+8x$. When we see $x+8$, we immediately recognize $x=-8$. However, to properly factor this equation, you need to factor out $-x$, not just $x$. Like this

$y=-x(x-8)$

...so now we see that $x=8$, and the intercept is $(8,0)$, as you correctly surmised it must be.

Answer (score -1):

*The thing is, 8 should be a positive number, otherwise I cannot have a parabola.*

This makes no sense.  Also, all your calculated points are correct.  It may relieve your confusion for you to know that the parabola is *concave* (i.e opens downward) and the vertex is *above the curve* and on the *positive* side of the y-axis.

Comment: Are you the same user as the following other PMar: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/349761/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/347147/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/325605/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/344183, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/357091, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/358074, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/370376, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/386375,  http://math.stackexchange.com/users/380039. If this is the case, could you please [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts?

Comment: Thank you all for your input. This was really bothering me. No, I'm not PMar or a follower.